# How to access the events and elements inside a SpriteKit GameScene?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I'm new to SpriteKit and starting to collect some experience.

What I currently can not understand is how to mix a GameScene with my own code?

So, there is a way to do all manually like this:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        //...
    }

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        //...
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        //...
    }
}
```

And then pass it to my `SpriteView`:

```
SpriteView(scene: GameScene())
```

This is fine, so I can do everything in Swift by code. To use a `.sks` GameScene file its also easy by using:

```
SpriteView(scene: SKScene(fileNamed: "MyScene")!)
```

**BUT** what I need to do to override the methods in `MyScene` and access the Sprites I created via the editor?

Answer (score 0):

I found it in the example. I can use the Custom Class property in the .sks file